# Embedded java at desktop application

Tags: java, maven, desktop-application

If it possible to build java desktop application with embedded JVM? I do not need to depend on the end user having the right JRE installed.

I build my application for Windows with `l4j maven plugin`.
Googling does not give needed results. Maybe you someone know how to do it with `maven` o `gradle`, not by some another utility like Avian, ProGuard and etc. ([Embed a JRE in a Windows executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258932/embed-a-jre-in-a-windows-executable))

Comment: Did'nt quite get exactly what you want to achieve here??

Comment: See here for IZPack usage about this (Mavenizable) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144096/embedding-a-jre-into-winrun4j-only-once-for-installer-and-application

Answer (score 0):

> The Maven plugin for Launch4j lets you generate the Launch4j
>   executable as part of the Maven build process. It supports Maven 2.0.4
>   and Launch4j 3.x.

See [here](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/README.adoc)

This is a sample of the configuration that you can try to use:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
                ...
        <configuration>
                    ...
            <jre>
                <!-- Specify path or minVersion or both. -->
                <path>bundled JRE path (%VAR%)</path>
                <bundledJre64Bit>true|false</bundledJre64Bit>
                <bundledJreAsFallback>true|false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                <minVersion>x.x.x[_xx]</minVersion>
                <maxVersion>x.x.x[_xx]</maxVersion>
                <jdkPreference>jreOnly|preferJre|preferJdk|jdkOnly</jdkPreference>
                <runtimeBits>64|64/32|32/64|32</runtimeBits>
                <!-- Heap sizes in MB and % of available memory. -->
                <initialHeapSize>MB</initialHeapSize>
                <initialHeapPercent>%</initialHeapPercent>
                <maxHeapSize>MB</maxHeapSize>
                <maxHeapPercent>%</maxHeapPercent>
                <opt>text (%VAR%)</opt>
            </jre>
                    ...
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```